# Account merge request status on user page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, contact

Is it possible to add a notification on the user page when one has requested attention via "contact us", for intervention such as requesting an account merge?

It might say something like: "Merge Request Pending"

I have just submitted such a request (due to a defunct OpenID provider) and it would be reassuring, as there is no way to know whether the request *actually* went through, or just said it went through.